# Substring function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to remove any underscore character that is coming into my string field, the position of the underscore character is not set so it could be anywhere.

I am trying to use this query, but I am getting NULL if the field has no underscore.

SUBSTR('SE8000901008', 1, INSTR('SE8000901008', '_') -1 ) --result here is null

SUBSTR('SE8000901008_', 1, INSTR('SE8000901008_', '_') -1 ) --result here is SE8000901008

Your help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: add a `WHERE` and check if instr is bigger than 0

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove underscore, then `replace` is probably better option that `substr + instr` combination.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'SE8000901008' from dual union all
  3     select 'SE8000901008_' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    replace(col, '_') result
  7  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SE8000901008                   SE8000901008
SE8000901008_                  SE8000901008

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any underscre, and the select another option

```
with test (col) as
    (select 'SE8000901008' from dual union all
     select 'SE8000901008_' from dual
    )
SELECT
CASE WHEN INSTR(col, '_') > 0 then
  SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '_') -1 )
ELSe col
ENd IF
FROM test
```

| IF |
| --- |
| SE8000901008 |
| SE8000901008 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r8lJk0PK)